# How to tell where the memory went in Linux

Tags: linux, memory-management

I have a long running process that I suspect has a memory leak.  I use `top` to monitor the memory levels of each process and nothing uses more than 15% of the total RAM.  The machine has 4GB of RAM and the process starts with well over 3GB free.  The process itself does very heavy, custom calculations on several MB of data.  It takes a single core at 100%.

As time goes on, memory disappears but `top` does not blame my long running process.  Instead, the "cached" and "buffers" memory increases and the "free" memory is reduced to as low as 2MB.  The process eventually finishes its job and exits without issue but the memory never comes back.  Should I be concerned or is this "normal"?  Are there other tools besides `top` that can provide a deeper understanding?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's normal.  Your process is operating on files which are getting cached in memory.  If there is "memory pressure" (demand from other programs) then that cache memory will be relinquished.  The first time I wrote an X widget to show how much memory was "free" it took me a while to get used to the idea that free memory is doing you no good:  Best to have it all in use doing *some* kind of caching until it's needed elsewhere!

Comment: Thanks, very insightful.  Do you know some good resources that help people to learn these concepts?  This is the first I've heard of "memory pressure"?

Comment: [The Design and Implementation of the FreeBSD Operating System](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0201702452?tag=benjac-20) will take you from the design decisions right down to the code.  I wanted to recommend one of the older, *shorter* editions like _The Design And Implementation of the 4.3BSD Operating System_ but it appears to be out of print.

Comment: Sounds good!  Does FreeBSD handle memory similar to Linux 2.6?

Comment: I just happen to know that the *Design And Implementation...* series is strong on OS concepts.  I don't know of a similar Linux book.  Perhaps post a new question to ask?